# How to draw AdMob Banner on Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, admob

Is it possible to somehow draw AdMob AdView Banner over the custom view on canvas?
Clearly shown in this figure

http://rghost.ru/8Tpt5bpFR/image.png
http://rghost.ru/88lvrGVfB/image.png

Draw in this place

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas holst)
{
  super.onDraw(holst);


holst.drawRect(0,0,w,h, whitekraska);//прямоугольник на весь экран

holst.drawBitmap(bottom,0,h-140, kraska1); //цветной растянутый прямоугольник

**DrawAdMobBanner(),x,y;**

invalidate();

}
```

Comment: what class does your custom view extend?

Comment: You could just have your custom view and the adView as children of a relative layout.

Comment: @Elltz class Canvaz extends **View**

Comment: @karaokyo please example, I tried to play with layout, but I did not work out

Comment: I do not use markup, everything is done by programatically
and the class is shown as

`Canvaz canva = new Canvaz(this.getContext());
MainActivity.activz.setContentView(  canva );`

Comment: okay Sir, you need to get the position of the last item, and then place it there, like the solution is suggesting, you can always wrap it in a RelativeLayout or extend it, my bet is LinearLayout with orientation 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F00"/>
    <fragment android:name="com.mypackage.myapplication.fragment.AdFragment"
        android:id="@+id/ad_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Replace the View with your custom view, obv.